# Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл используется другим процессом

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

Всем доброго времени суток.

Возникла следующая проблема:
На форме есть ListBox, в данный ListBox, я добавляю итемы в виде "Картинка+Текст":

```
<ListBox Name="lstTest">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="50">
                <Image Name="imgTest" Height="24" Width="24" Margin="0" Source="{Binding path_img}"/>
                <TextBlock Name="txtTest" Margin="5, 15, 0, 0" Text="{Binding nameTest}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Добавляю итемы следующим образом:

```
lstTest.Items.Add(new DirectoryListing() { path_img = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + "\\Test\\favicon.png", nameTest= "Тестовый итем" });
```

Класс "DirectoryListing" выглядит следующим образом:

```
public partial class DirectoryListing
{
    public string path_img { get; set; }
    public string nameTest { get; set; }
}
```

И собственно, вся суть проблемы в том, что при попытки удалить всю папку с картинкой (предварительно удалив Итем из ListBox) возникает ошибка - "Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу "favicon.png", так как этот файл используется другим процессом."

Удалить я пытаюсь следующим образом:

```
foreach (DirectoryListing di in lstTest.Items)
{
    if (di == lstTest.SelectedItem)
    {
        di.nameTest= null;
        di.path_img = null;
        lstTest.Items.Remove(lstTest.SelectedItem);
        di.Dispose();
        break;
    }
}
FileSystem.DeleteDirectory(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + "\\Test", DeleteDirectoryOption.DeleteAllContents);
```

Суть то мне ясна, что нужно как то освободить этот файл картинки от моей программы, но как это сделать?

Comment: Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow на русском!

Comment: `partial class DirectoryListing` а что в той части класса, что вы не показали?

Comment: Реализация Dispose и все.

Comment: А что диспозите то в той реализации?

Comment: Попробуйте этот код для удаления не пустой директории `Directory.Delete(destinationFolder, true);`.

Comment: Без изменений. И директория не пустая, там помимо картинки есть еще файлы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы получить нужное поведение, вам придётся использовать загрузку изображения в память вместо использования URI.

Например, вот так:

```
var bitmap = BitmapFrame.Create(
memoryStream, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);

 image.Source = bitmap; // image - ваш Image из разметки
```

Ключевое здесь - BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad.
Этот флаг заставляет WPF загрузить данные в память и освободить ресурс.

Можно добавлять полученные битмапы в лист и биндить также, как делаете вы.
Остаётся только загрузить данные в MemoryStream.

Comment: Во! Вот это помогло. Благодарю.

Comment: Отметьте тогда мой ответ как решающий вашу проблему